# Trying to apply pseudo selector 'onclick' to an list element

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML element I am targeting:

```
<li id="project-1">1</li>
```

This is where the error occurs, the IDE complains that 'onclick' is not a pseudo selector for the list element. Here is the CSS.

```
#project-1:onclick {
    background: gray;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    animation: roll 3s ease;
}
```

How can I apply onclick to this list item?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no `:onclick` selector... There is the [onclick]-selector that selects elements with a specific onclick attribute. What you trying to achieve requires javascript

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is the best at handling events and interactions with the DOM. I would suggest adding an `eventListener` to the element you are targeting and adding a CSS class to get the styling you want.

for example:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('project-1');
element.addEventListener('click', () => {
  element.classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: gray;
  width: 75px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  animation: roll 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<li id="project-1">1</li>
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use <li id="project-1" onclick="setClassFunction()">1</li>.

Comment: @zero2579 that is poor advice as that is considered to be "bad practice". In modern web development, you always bind an event by using the `eventListener`. This makes maintenance easier, keeps your HTML code cleaner and is easier to bug fix as you don't have to search for the functions.

Comment: @tacoshy of course, you're totally right!